# How to access the block ID in hook_block_view_alter()?

Tags: 8, blocks

How can I access the block ID in hook_block_view_alter()?

```
function mysite_block_view_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {

  if ('my-block-id' == $block->maybe_there_is_some_method_that_returns_the_id()) {
    // Do something.
  }
}
```

Is there some way to inspect the $block variable?  I'm finding that calling var_dump or kint inside of hook_block_view_alter() has no effect.

Actually, I have not been able to confirm that the hook fires at all:

```
function mysite_block_view_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {

  \Drupal::logger('mei')->warning('did it fire at all');
}
```

The above does not result in any messages in the log.

Comment: Do you enabled this module ?

Comment: Yes, the module is enabled.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it, but I think this is the way to get the block ID: $block->get('id')